# Is there a way to log the reason of an Invalid memory access in JNA

Tags: java, jna

I have the following error when invoking Java code from C using JNA:

```
Native Exception in org.InvokerPackageCallback@3ba987b8
java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
  at com.sun.jna.Native.getStringBytes(Native Method)
  at com.sun.jna.Native.getString(Native.java:2248)
  at com.sun.jna.Pointer.getString(Pointer.java:681)
  at com.sun.jna.Structure.readField(Structure.java:743)
  at com.sun.jna.Structure.read(Structure.java:605)
  at org.PackageStruct$ByReference.read(PackageStruct.java:102)
  at com.sun.jna.Structure.autoRead(Structure.java:2234)
  at com.sun.jna.Structure.conditionalAutoRead(Structure.java:576)
  at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.convertArgument(CallbackReference.java:650)
  at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.invokeCallback(CallbackReference.java:571)
  at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.callback(CallbackReference.java:610)
  at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeVoid(Native Method)
  at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:415)
  at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:361)
  at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:265)
```

In my use case the C code invoke the `publish_package_fct_pt` function which is mapped to a Java interface method. This method has only one structure argument:

```
void publish_package_fct_ptr(void (*pf) (PackageStruct));
```

I use the following  library:

```
public interface MyLib extends Library {
   public void publish_package_fct_ptr(InvokerPackage callback);

   public interface InvokerPackage extends Callback {
      void invoke(PackageStruct.ByReference pack);
   }
}
```

with the following structure definition:

```
public class PackageStruct extends Structure {
  public NativeLong id;
  public int type;
  public int subtype;   
  public String configuration;   
  public String name;
  public NativeLong date;

  public PackageStruct(Pointer peer) {
    super(peer);
  }

 public PackageStruct() {
   super();
 }

 protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("id", "type", "subtype", "configuration", "name", "date");
 }

 public static class ByReference extends PackageStruct implements Structure.ByReference {
  public void read() {
     super.read();
  }
}
```

The C structure is:

```
struct PackageStruct {
  long id;
  int type;
  int subtype;
  const char *configuration;
  const char *name;
  long date;
};
```

It worked correctly before I added the `configuration` field, and I have the exception now. I "think" that the `configuration` field points to nothing, which might be the reason why I have this error.

Do you agree with my hypothesis? And is there a mean in JNA to log the `com.sun.jna.Structure.readField` to know for which field I have this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Invalid Memory Access" error thrown by JNA is a "graceful" handling of native memory errors caught by [Structured Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-160). So to answer the question in the title, unfortunately you can't get more details from the native side.

All you really need to know is that either **You are attempting to access native memory that you do not own** or **Your native memory allocation failed**.

Your mappings look correct, but you haven't shown the code where you actually call the `publish_package_fct_ptr()` method. That's where the problem probably exists.

However, the fact that it's a callback points to a very common problem with JNA and callbacks, in which the memory is released before you use it so I'll hazard a guess that's the problem you are experiencing here.

JNA tracks its memory allocation using the `Memory` class.  If you don't provide the Structure a pointer when you construct it, it will allocate the necessary memory and store that internally in a `Memory` object.  This works for most uses of structures.

However, releasing the native memory is tied to Java's garbage collection. When the Structure is GC'd its internal memory object is also GC'd and as part of its `finalize()` execution it releases the native memory.

If the callback is the last time you reference the Structure in Java, it becomes unreachable and is eligible to be GC'd.  In some cases, this could happen before the callback finishes executing, taking away that native memory allocation.

If you are using JDK 9+, using a `ReachabilityFence` after the callback will solve this problem.  For JDK 8 and earlier, you may have to do some other code manipulation of the Structure after it's used in the callback, to ensure Java retains a reference to it (and its underlying native memory).

(Aside/unrelated to the question: you don't need to declare a Structure ByReference if used as a method argument. That's the default. You might also find the `@FieldOrder` annotation cleaner than the override of the `getFieldOrder()` method.)

Comment: Thank you!! It appears that its much more complex than I thought (because in most of the cases JNA makes things look simple even if they are not)

Comment: @Daniel Would you please let me know how did you use ReachabilityFence  here? I am also facing similar issue.

Comment: @GauravJeswani I support JDK8 on my project so I don't use `ReachabilityFence`.  But all you need to do is reference the variable after the callback, e.g., just add `Reference.reachabilityFence(pack)` into the code after the `invoke()` call.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I am also on Java8, how did you handle that in Java8 then? I was just thinking to test with Java9.

Comment: I m getting this error when calling callback on high frequency :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f1mDNFuu6f1NQM8Q9bSIiivFzTBTfax7/view?usp=sharing   Can you please give some pointers to debug the issue here?

Comment: And I am using static reference to callback.

Comment: @GauravJeswani the SIGSEGV is also indicative of memory error, same cause.  Any manipulation of the Memory object should work. You could `readByte(0)` (I've tested this and it works) or possibly try generating the `toString()`.  I'd suggest putting them in a finally block.  One method I think would work that I haven't tried is using `dispose()`. It's protected so you would have to extend `Memory` to use it, but you could then also make it closeable (overriding `close()` with `dispose()` and use a try with resources block to effectively do the same thing.

Comment: The objects is being created and destroyed by native library, it is just being passed to callback for processing. I have added my scenario in details here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70655937/jna-callback-pointer-is-use-crashing-the-application

Would be really helpful if you can look into it and provide your opinion.