# When I use the jna method, the java call to c# keeps running with an error saying "java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access"

Tags: java, c#, c++, jna

When I use the jna method, java calls c# with a constant error.

**java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access**

c# code is below (64 bit),

```
namespace EwpDeleteBlank
{

    public static class RemoveBlankPage
    {

    }
}
```

c++ code is below (pch.h and pch.cpp, 64 bit),
pch.h is below,

```
#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H


#include "framework.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define  MYLIBAPI  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) 

MYLIBAPI  void deleteBlankPages();


#endif //PCH_H
```

pch.cpp is below,

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <string>



#using "C:\Users\zhang\Desktop\g\ewp-delete-blank\bin\x64\Debug\RemoveBlankPage.dll"

using namespace EwpDeleteBlank;
using namespace std;

void deleteBlankPages() {

    RemoveBlankPage ^obj = gcnew RemoveBlankPage();
}
```

java code is below,

```
public interface MyLibraryInterface extends Library {

    MyLibraryInterface instance = (MyLibraryInterface) Native.loadLibrary("Dll1.dll", MyLibraryInterface.class);

    void deleteBlankPages();
}

：
MyLibraryInterface.instance.deleteBlankPages();
```

but when run , it show error,

```
java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
```

Comment: Why can't you call c directly from java.  Why are you going from java to C# to C++ to C?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to log the reason of an Invalid memory access in JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69541798/is-there-a-way-to-log-the-reason-of-an-invalid-memory-access-in-jna)

Comment: JNA is just calling the native method which gives no information about memory.  You haven't shown the code inside the `RemoveBlankPage` method, but whatever it is, it's accessing memory it doesn't own.  This is not a java/JNA problem, it's a C problem.

Comment: Yes, the code is that way.  
RemoveBlankPage is a very simple empty c# class, just a test, but the call doesn't work, the  
Dll1.dll is compiled from pch.cpp.

Comment: I see `using namespace std;` have you tried extending `StdCallLibrary` rather than `Library` in JNA?